# Facebook API share on user feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

when i try to POST->v3.2->/me/feed with all permissions Facebook api returns me "(#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission".message isn't very descriptive. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not very clear, but it´s not possible to post to the user wall anymore. You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

Answer (score 0):

Posting to user wall is deprecated as per current Facebook policy...The error message that you are getting is actually wrong. They need to change that...

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

If you visit the above link, you can find that,

**The publish_actions permission will be deprecated. This permission granted apps access to publish posts to Facebook as the logged in user. Apps created from today onwards will not have access to this permission. Apps created before today that have been previously approved to request publish_actions can continue to do so until August 1, 2018. No further apps will be approved to use publish_actions via app review. Developers currently utilizing publish_actions are encouraged to switch to Facebook's Share dialogs for web, iOS and Android.**